# Regrex string to match a list in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm looking for a string match finder to test if the following string in the output can be extracted from the list `stringsToTest`.

I have a regex string but can't get the right combination. There are a lot of possibilites for this.

My actual list is about 140,000 strings long and I only want this combination to find:

```
stringsToTest = list("abc/a3d)-1-B-3-B","dec/d93)-B-1-3",
                     "vdiek/asdf899)-1-B-B-B-1-3-4","avd/asd/vde)-1-B-3-4",
                     "ab33/dfv)-B-12-B","abc/ade)-1")
```

I use grepl b/c it gives me a true or false for the following string

```r
grepl(stringsToTest, #pattern=#pattern="([:alnum:]+\\/){2}\\){1}a\\-]{1}([:alnum:]*a\\-]){3}.*$")){
    pattern="[:alnum:]+[:punct:]+[:alnum:]+[:punct:]+[:alnum:]+[:punct:]+[:alnum:]+[:punct:]+[:alnum:]+[:punct:]+[:alnum:].*$")
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

My output I would like would be. The foward slash, parethesis, and hyphons need to be exactlly the same. My cut off is a forward slash followed by a parathesis followed by three hyphons. I will except more hyphons beyond this if there are as
shown in the example.

Expected output:

```
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Note the TRE pattern requires POSIX character classes to be wrapped with a bracket expression, `[:punct:]` matches `:`, `p`, `u`, `n`, `c`, and `t` chars.

Comment: I do not quite understand your requirements. Why is the 4th item, `avd/asd/vde)-1-B-3-4`, FALSE? Well, a guess: `"^[[:alnum:]]+/[[:alnum:]]+\\)-[[:alnum:]]+-"`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jxT7ox/1)

Comment: Or, `"^\\w+/\\w+\\)-\\w+-"` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/jxT7ox/2/))

Comment: These are breeding pedigrees. So the fourth item is of a different generation. whereas the other are a minimum of a F4 generation. So the / is F1, - F2, - F3, - F4. I just need to know if these are a minimum of F4. Except the 6th item, this is of a F2 generation so it would be false. The third item is of a F8 generation but It would be true becuase it meets the requirment of a F4 generation. The fourth item is of a different type of pedigree and would like to exclude these using the pattern of /, -, -, -

Comment: I am not sure this is helpful to determine the regex. To write the right regex, we need to understand what text we need to match. What kind of chars should follow which kind of chars? What kind of chars can be in between? Are there any static, hardcoded parts ?

Comment: Hardcoded parts are the /, -, -, -. In between these are any character or number upper or lower case.

Comment: But this means the fourth item is TRUE, `/[[:alnum:]]+\)(?:-[[:alnum:]]+){3}`, see https://regex101.com/r/jxT7ox/3/. What makes the 4th items FALSE? In words? I can't tell Item 1 from Item 4.

Comment: The fourth item is false because it is a three-way cross hence the two / before it is selfed hence the -. whereas the others are of a two-way cross hence only one /

Comment: So, we come to `^[[:alnum:]]+/[[:alnum:]]+\)(?:-[[:alnum:]]+){3}`, see https://regex101.com/r/jxT7ox/4. See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/GOniHU)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
^[[:alnum:]]+/[[:alnum:]]+\)(?:-[[:alnum:]]+){3}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jxT7ox/4). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[[:alnum:]]+` - one or more letters or digits
- `/` - a `/` char
- `[[:alnum:]]+` - one or more letters/digits
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `(?:-[[:alnum:]]+){3}` - three occurrences of a `-` and then one or more letters/digits sequences.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/GOniHU):

```r
stringsToTest = list("abc/a3d)-1-B-3-B","dec/d93)-B-1-3",
                     "vdiek/asdf899)-1-B-B-B-1-3-4","avd/asd/vde)-1-B-3-4",
                     "ab33/dfv)-B-12-B","abc/ade)-1")
grepl(stringsToTest, 
     pattern="^[[:alnum:]]+/[[:alnum:]]+\\)(?:-[[:alnum:]]+){3}")
## => [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```